# Understanding recursion during QuickSort

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

I am new to c++ and going through one quick sort algorithm from http://geeksquiz.com/quick-sort/

Here is the code snippet i am unable to understand that how come the value of low and high is getting changed

```
int partition (int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];    // pivot
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
        // If current element is smaller than or
        // equal to pivot
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

/* The main function that implements QuickSort
 arr[] --> Array to be sorted,
  low  --> Starting index,
  high  --> Ending index */
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now
           at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        // Separately sort elements before
        // partition and after partition
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Please help me to understand the above logic.

Comment: The best way to understand this logic it to take out a piece of paper, and a pencil, and write down a small array, say five elements. Then, walk through the code in `partition()` one line at a time, keeping track of every variable, and the contents of the array.

Comment: `low` and `high` are just boundaries of the recursive sorts

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i can able to understand the logic behind partition(). One thing which i cant understand is the recursion logic and the value update for low. As no where in the function we are updating the value of low/high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a partition. Post condition of `partition` is that everything to the left of the pivot element will be less than or equal to element at partition and everything to the right of the pivot element will be greater than or equal to the pivot element. Recurse on left and right subarray.

By loop invariant, you'll have a sorted array.

---

For sake of simplicity, let's say your partition always returns the middle element.

You know by the post condition of `partition` ensures that left is at most the pivot element and right is at least the pivot element.

You now recurse sort the left by recursively calling quicksort with `low == low` and `high == pi - 1`. `pi` is in the correct space, so you don't need to worry about that. Finally, you call quicksort on the right array with `low == pi+1` and `high == high`.

Repeat until everything is sorted (i.e., `!(low < high)`).

The recursion task is explained well in this graph (where we assume that pivot is the middle element every time). This also conveniently shows the average case `O(n log n)` time complexity.

[image: quicksort complexity explained]

Comment: Thanks Erip ..
. But i  want to understand at what step of the logic the low/high values are getting updated .

Comment: @vivek You're updating `high` and `low` with `pi-1` and `pi+1`, respectively, on each recursion level. This corresponds to _Recurse on left and right subarray._

Answer (score 2):

You have clarified your question that you understand the logic behind partition(), but not the recursion. Ok.

You must start with the assumption than `quickSort()` is going to sort your array. Accept it as a given. An axiom. It must be true. You are assuired that `quickSort()` will sort your array. You must accept this statement as an unquestionable truth, as a starting point.

Then, you already understand that `partition()` divides the list into two halfs. Based on that, you can draw the following conclusions:

1. The half of the array before the pivoting element contains only values that are less than the pivot element.
2. The half of the array after the pivoting element contains only values that are greater than the pivot element.
3. 1 & 2 come as a result of the `partition()` operation, which you stated you understand fully. Given 1 & 2, as a starting point, you can then conclude that if the halfs of the array referenced in 1 & 2 were fully sorted themselves, than the entire array will have to be fully sorted.
4. And how do you make 1 & 2 true? Well, you apply the `quickSort()` algorithm recursively. You just agreed that `quickSort()` will fully sort the array it gets. So, after `quickSort()` recursively sorts the two halfs, the end result must be a completely sorted list.

Q.E.D.

P.S. The term "half of the array", used above, is a loosely-used term. The actual size of each half of the array won't, of course, be exactly half of the original array. This has no impact on the overall logic.